# To merge not all dll's with ILMerge

Tags: c#, ilmerge, zxing.net

Is it possible to merge not all, but just some of reference dll's with `ILMerge`? I have two references - `Zxsign` and `DirectShowLib`. I did `ILMerge` just with `DirectShowLib`:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" SnapShot.exe DirectShowLib.dll /out:aa.exe
```

FIles `zxing.dll` and `zxing.presentation.dll` was placed near `aa.exe`. Got exception during call to zxing package:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

    ************** Exception Text **************
    System.Exception: Timeout waiting to get picture
       at SnapShot.Capture.Click()
       at SnapShot.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


    ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
    mscorlib
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8936 (WinRelRS4.050727-8900)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    aa
        Assembly Version: 1.0.6890.24360
        Win32 Version: 1.0.6890.24360
        CodeBase: file:///D:/C%23nonsens/DirectShowSamples-2010-February/Samples/Capture/DxSnap/bin/Release/New%20folder/aa.exe
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Windows.Forms
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8922 (WinRelRS4.050727-8900)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8934 (WinRelRS4.050727-8900)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Drawing
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8922 (WinRelRS4.050727-8900)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
    ----------------------------------------

    ************** JIT Debugging **************
    To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
    application or computer (machine.config) must have the
    jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
    The application must also be compiled with debugging
    enabled.

    For example:

    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

    When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
    will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
    rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Is it possible somehow manage `ILMerge` in order not to have such error?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the following nuget
`Install-package ILMerge.MSBuild.Tasks`

Example of the target in `.csproj` between `<Project> </Project>`

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MergeAsm Include="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll" />
    <MergeAsm Include="$(OutputPath)2nd.dll" />
    <MergeAsm Include="$(OutputPath)3th.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MergedAssembly>$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(AssemblyName).dll</MergedAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="ILMerge @(MergeAsm) -&gt; $(MergedAssembly)" Importance="high" />
  <ILMerge InputAssemblies="@(MergeAsm)" OutputFile="$(MergedAssembly)" TargetKind="SameAsPrimaryAssembly" />
</Target>
```

The MergeAsm you can define every dll you wanna merge to the primary as shown in the example 2nd.dll and 3th.dll